# Embed vimeo video: expand option is missing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have written a small application to embed Vimeo videos and everything is working just fine, except expand video option in Internet Explorer.

**Info: I am getting my video data (including the embed code) from vimeo api.**

I have googled a bit, and found many cases where people where having problems with the embed code (not playing, missing options, etc). But not a similar case and not a solution.

Everything is working just fine in Chrome.

For IE I have tried/checked:

•   All over Https

•   Disabling hardware acceleration (this got the HD and Vimeo button to work)

•   I frame has allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen=""

•   HTML5 video handling (some people reported IE had some problems regarding HTML5…)

```
* Manipulated the embed iframe to include:
- Sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups"
- Src will include ?api=1
```

**Image Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**Image Internet Explorer**

[image]

Inspected the embedded code in IE shows a button "Enter full screen". This has the class:

```
.no-fullscreen-support.player .fullscreen {
Display: none !important;
}
```

Is there something else I can try? Missing?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you go to the original Vimeo site with the video through Explorer is the option full screen then available?

Comment: Yes, then it works with IE. I also tried the example "Pre-existing player" from https://github.com/vimeo/player.js, but I am getting the same problem as my question.